# What is the difference between Algorithm and Logic?

Tags: computer-science

I know an algorithm is an effective method expressed as a finite list of well-defined instructions for calculating a function.But how we can differentiate it from Logic?

Comment: @Rob is correct here. An algorithm is the set of instructions and logic is the reasoning / usage of these instructions.

Answer (score 9):

Wow your question took me on a voyage and I found something!! This may not stand as an answer but putting it here as a reference.

**[Algorithm = Logic + Control](http://www.doc.ic.ac.uk/~rak/papers/algorithm%20=%20logic%20+%20control.pdf)**

An algorithm can be regarded as consisting of a
logic component, which specifies the knowledge to be used in solving problems, and a control componentwhich determines the problem-solving strategies by
means of which that knowledge is used.

The logic
component determines the meaning of the algorithm
whereas the control component only affects its
effeciency. The effeciency of an algorithm can often be
improved by improving the control component without
changing the logic of the algorithm.

Answer (score 3):

Logic would be the reason behind the well-defined instructions.